# error unknown filesystem grub rescue windows 10

Tags: windows-10, grub

I had win 10 and lubuntu on 2 separate partitions.

I removed the second partition using Disk Management. Now when I restart laptop it goes into grub mode and what ever I try i get error.

```
error unknown filesystem
```

How to fix so I can load windows 10?

Comment: What is "The second partition"?

Comment: Fixed. I installed win 7 on second partition. Laptop works.